# proof of the non-messing up theorem

Tags: algorithm, sorting, theorem-proving

I can't prove the non-messing up theorem. That's the theorem which states that if you sort the rows and then the columns of a matrix, the rows will remain sorted.

I've read a sketch of a proof that states:

- sort the rows
- permute the rows to sort the first column
- permute the rows, for each one discarding it's first element, to sort the second column and so on.
- The invariant is that the rows remain sorted at each step. (whatever that means - I'm quoting the steps)

I can't proove this. Can someone give me a more detailed proof or a link to some paper?

Comment: You end up with n items in a column, each with a number greater than them in the column over. If you sort those, the column to the right grows faster than the column to the left, so it will remain sorted. Induct to all the rows, and you're done.

Comment: this is a nice question -- for [math stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: This question is more appropriate for the math stackexchange site.

Answer (score 3):

**Simple paragraph explanation**: If the rows are sorted, and you have column A, column B, a number `r` in column A, and `n` numbers in column A less than or equal to `r`, then: there are at most `n` numbers in column B that are less than `r` (corresponding to the `n` numbers in column A). The rest are either equal to or greater than `r`. You can take `r` to be any number in column A, and the result will still hold. Then you use the same logic for every column.

**A longer explanation with pictures**:

We can start with a simple matrix, already sorted by rows:

[image]

If we sort the colored blocks by their first number, we get this matrix (note, this is essentially sorting column A, but also dragging column B with it):

[image]

Now, in this next image, 2 is less than or equal to everything in blue. Therefore, no matter how you sort column B, row 1 will still be sorted:

[image]

In the next image, because the rows and column A are sorted, 3 is less than or equal to everything in purple. Therefore, when column B is sorted, the number next to 3 must be greater than or equal to it. Because of this, we know that row 2 will stay sorted.

[image]

In the next image, because the rows and column A are sorted, 3 is less than or equal to everything in black. Therefore, when column B is sorted, the number next to 3 must be greater than or equal to it. Because of this, we know that row 3 will stay sorted.

[image]

For the last row, we can use the same logic. We can also note, however, that obviously there is a number that will keep the last row sorted (the one that's currently next to it, 7). If 7 is not there, another number > 7 *must* be there after column B is sorted. Row 4 will remain sorted:

[image]

We end up with this:

[image]

The rows will **not always** be sorted for columns that haven't been sorted yet. For instance, note this matrix whose rows are sorted:

```
[4 7 8  9]
[1 5 10 12]
[2 3 6  11]
```

If we sort the first two columns in the above matrix, we get:

```
[1 3 8  9]
[2 5 10 12]
[4 7 6  11]
```

Row 3 is not sorted. However, it will get the number `10` after sorting column 3, and everything will be fine again.

Comment: You give the key property needed (though I think you need to add the condition `B > A`, and I would also go the full distance and explain that we know the property must hold because otherwise the pigeonhole principle would imply that at least one row is not sorted), but for me this isn't quite a proof.  What we have to show translates to: "In the final matrix, for each row i and column j, j' <= j implies x[i][j'] <= x[i][j]."  Assume inductively that it holds for all j <= k.  (Clearly it holds for j = 1.) ...

Comment: ...  Because each column is sorted, for each i, there can be at most i-1 numbers in column k that are < x[i][k] (they all appear in the vertical strip beginning at x[1][k]).  By your property (with "<=" changed to "<"), this means that there can be at most i-1 numbers in column k+1 that are < x[i][k]; these will also occupy a vertical strip, this time beginning at x[1][k+1].  This strip ends somewhere above row i, and it exhausts all numbers < x[i][k], so x[i][k+1] >= x[i][k].  Since this holds for all i, we have established that the property continues to hold for column k+1.

Comment: B > A is another way to show it. the rest is basically what I said in my first paragraph though - just a little more formal

Comment: Sorry. Didn't mean to hit enter. Tablets.... I will edit it when I get the chance. I was really going for "if you can't explain it simply, you don't understand it well enough" though. on the other hand, my example could definitely be better :). @j_random_hacker

Comment: What I meant is that if B < A then your first sentence doesn't hold.  I'm all for simple explanations, but I haven't seen this problem before and what you had given wasn't quite enough for me -- I just needed to spell it out out to convince myself :)

Comment: I guess I did fail at explaining it then if it wasn't enough for a 30k user :). I hadnt seen it either. It's an interesting property.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I edited the answer and gave a longer explanation with pictures. Did I make it easy enough to understand this time?

Comment: You did, and I appreciate the effort :)  My ongoing quibble about A and B is that I originally interpreted A and B as *variables* containing column numbers -- and in that case the correctness of your first claim requires that B > A (i.e. that column A is somewhere to the left of column B), but you don't state this.  But I guess you just meant "There's a column named A, and a column named B", and in that case it's pretty clear that A has to be to the left of B.

Comment: Ah ok. I'll make that clear when I get the chance :). Thanks! @j_random_hacker